# Hide price until login and display button - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide the price for the users that aren't logged on to my site. I managed to hide the price for single products and for variable products. In variable products that have different prices for single variants, this code does not work. How can I fix it?

```
add_action( 'init', 'nascondi_prezzo_se_non_loggato' );
function nascondi_prezzo_se_non_loggato() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false' );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'mostra_testo_alternativo', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'mostra_testo_alternativo', 11 );
    }
}

function mostra_testo_alternativo() {
    echo '<a href="http://spaf.whitelabstaging.it/registrazione-login/"><div class="button-prezzo">' . __( 'Accedi per vedere i prezzi', 'JupiterX' ) . '</div></a>';
}
```

This is the code that I used and that only partially solves the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code snippet below. The price is set to an empty string that won't display the price for users who aren't logged in. This uses the filter `woocommerce_get_price_html` which returns the code that outputs the price. In the empty string, add what you want displayed instead of the price.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_not_logged_in', 10, 2 );
function hide_price_not_logged_in( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Anytime! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

To help everyone: I use the code above that hides the price and part of my code to hide the add to cart button

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_not_logged_in', 10, 2 );
function hide_price_not_logged_in( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}

add_action( 'init', 'nascondi_prezzo_se_non_loggato' );
function nascondi_prezzo_se_non_loggato() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false' );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'mostra_testo_alternativo', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'mostra_testo_alternativo', 11 );
    }
}

function mostra_testo_alternativo() {
    echo '<a href="#"><div class="button-prezzo">' . __( 'Accedi per vedere i prezzi', 'your-theme-name' ) . '</div></a>';
}
```